# How to get database connection details without longing to cpanel in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, php, mysql, sql, wp-config

I am creating a WordPress plugin and in my plugin i need to do some SQL statements ,in the site i am working on i have access to WP-admin but i cant get to the files to get database name and password from WP-config that i need in

```
 mysqli_connect("host", "user_name", "password","database_name");
```

i believe there is a way to do that in PHP  like all plugins in WordPress but i couldn't find out how !

Comment: Why you need a separate mysql connection? You can use `wpdb` to easily handle the job. It's secure and standard way to do things within plugin. read more here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

Comment: thanks this  is the clue i needed  @Sabbir Hasan

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to know I could help you.

Comment: Also, Anna, while Sabbir Hasan is 100% correct and you should look to use `$wpdb`, you can always check your `wp-config.php` file for the full database credentials.

Comment: thanks your answer is great too!! actually i found it easier since i already used SQL statements in my code @ Tony Djukic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both answers were great and helped me a lot ,i used the following to get to wp-config file without really Knowing all database details

```
      require_once('../wp-config.php');
      include_once ('../wp-load.php');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD , DB_NAME);
```